# .NET Core IsPostback

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When i try to download the file, click count increases 5 sometimes 6 instead of 1 increment.I tried to use `Task.Delay(5000);` but it didn't work .I think I can solve it with the !ispostback method. What exactly is the equivalent of this method in asp.net core and how can i solve the problem.

```
public IActionResult Download(int id)
        {
            var essay = _essayBussRepository.GetWithId(id);
            essay.NumberOfDownloads = essay.NumberOfDownloads + 1;
            Task.Delay(5000);
            _essayBussRepository.Update(essay);


            string fileName = essay.PdfName;
            string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/w_essay_pdf/" + fileName);


            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

            return File(fileBytes, "application/force-download", fileName);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure this endpoint isn't being invoked multiple times? Are you calling this API from a browser (such as via fetch or AJAX), or Postman, or what?

Comment: `Task.Delay(5000);` is async, you need to `await` it

Comment: i am calling like that : `<a asp-action="Download" asp-route-id="@item.Id">`

Comment: As there is no concept of postback but there are other ways to manage state like ViewBag, TempData and Model binding. You can try those approaches in this as a workaround. This will help you handle those concerns easily.

Comment: `await` keyword works thank you so much. I don't know how I could be so careless...

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by turning into async.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(int id)
        {
            var essay = _essayBussRepository.GetWithId(id);
            essay.NumberOfDownloads = essay.NumberOfDownloads + 1;
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            _essayBussRepository.Update(essay);


            string fileName = essay.PdfName;
            string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/w_essay_pdf/" + fileName);


            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

            return File(fileBytes, "application/force-download", fileName);
        }
```

Comment: That's fine, but the wrong solution to this problem, IMO. It sounds like you have a larger issue that should be resolved instead, as a long term solution.